# SQL double negation, I just cant understand it.

Tags: sql

The question is "Find the properties (pids) that have at least ALL the meter types as the property id 7 has"

Theres a table with both the id's and the metertypes in called p__METER

SO this is what i thought would be correct but it doesnt return only the pid that Has both of the values, it also returns one that just has one value as well as the original property. Any idea's? This double negation stuff is crazy to understand.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT pid
    FROM property__PROPERTYMETER X
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT * FROM property__PROPERTYMETER Y
         WHERE pid = 7
         AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT * FROM property__PROPERTYMETER
           WHERE metertype = X.metertype
           AND pid = Y.pid ))
```

Comment: Your question seems incomplete: *"Find the properties (pids) that have at least ALL the meter types as the property id 7 has"*.

Comment: theres a table with a list of meter types and pids in, so I need to list all the pid that = meters PID 7 has. For this example pid 7 has metertype C14 and C2. So I somehow have to check that the other PIDS also have BOTH c14 and C2, however I dont seem to be able to do it :(

Comment: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). You're looking for `pid` where there does not exist a property related to `7` for which there does not exist a matching row for that `pid`/`metertype` combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a doubly nested query

Better to say 
"Find the properties (pids) that are NOT Missing ANY OF the meter types THAT the property id 7 has"
or

"Find the properties (pids) such that there does not exist a metertype belonging to pid 7 that does not also belong to this pid."

```
Select DISTINCT pid           -- outer query: "Show all pids ... "
From property_PROPERTYMETER X 
Where not Exists                  -- mid-query: "Where there is no pid:7 metertype ..."
   (Select * From property_PROPERTYMETER y   
    Where metertype = X.metertype 
      And pid = 7
      And Not exists 
         (Select * from property_PROPERTYMETER -- inner Qry: "..not also in this pid."
          Where metertype = y.metertype 
            And pid = x.pid))
```

Answer (score 2):

The innermost query should verify that the outermost property has all metertypes of the middle property.  In your example, it verifies that the middle property has none of the metertypes of the outer property.

So you've got the innermost query inside out.  Change:

```
       WHERE metertype = X.metertype
       AND pid = X.pid ))
```

To:

```
       WHERE metertype = Y.metertype
       AND pid = X.pid ))
```

Comment: any ideas on how to make sure it doesnt bring up PID 7 in the results?

Answer (score 0):

What about a left join?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT pid
    FROM property__PROPERTYMETER X
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT * FROM property__PROPERTYMETER Y
         LEFT JOIN property__PROPERTYMETER Z 
              ON Z.metertype = Y.metertype AND Z.pid = X.pid
         WHERE Y.pid = 7 AND Z.pid is null
         )
```